# TypeError: 'Adam' object is not callable

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to use [this method](https://kozodoi.me/python/deep%20learning/pytorch/tutorial/2022/03/29/discriminative-lr.html) of updating a pretrained model based on learning rate for each group of layers. I apply the same method but I get this error

```
TypeError: 'Adam' object is not callable
```

This is the code for the training loop:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple

def train_step(model: torch.nn.Module, 
               dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader, 
               loss_fn: torch.nn.Module, 
               optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
               device: torch.device):

  # Put model in train mode
  model.train()

  # Setup train loss and train accuracy values
  train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0

  # Loop through data loader data batches
  for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):

      # Send data to target device
      X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

      # 1. Forward pass
      y_pred = model(X)

      # 2. Calculate and accumulate loss
      loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
      train_loss += loss.item() 

      # 3. Optimizer zero grad
      optimizer.step()
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      # 4. Loss backward
      loss.backward()

      # 5. Optimizer step
      # optimizer.step()

      # Calculate and accumulate accuracy metric across all batches
      y_pred_class = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1), dim=1)
      train_acc += (y_pred_class == y).sum().item()/len(y_pred)

  # Adjust metrics to get average loss and accuracy per batch 
  train_loss = train_loss / len(dataloader)
  train_acc = train_acc / len(dataloader)
  return train_loss, train_acc
```

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 100

# Recreate an instance of TinyVGG
model_0 = model
device = device

# Setup loss function and optimizer
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = class_weights)
# params= model_0.parameters()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(parameters_1) 
# optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model_0.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
# optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model_0.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-6)
# scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=20, gamma=0.5)

SaveBestModel()

# Start the timer
from timeit import default_timer as timer 
start_time = timer()

# Train model_0 
model_0_results = train(model=model_0, 
                        train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
                        test_dataloader=test_dataloader,
                        optimizer=optimizer,
                        loss_fn=loss_fn,
                        epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                        device=device)
```

I tried to add the parameters of the model beside the parameters and learning rate as the same as original Adam but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that parameters_1 is some dict of parameters.
try unpacking it: `optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(**parameters_1)`

Comment: no it is a list

Comment: the output of the len(parameters_1),type(parameters_1) is 62 which is the number of model i used(resnet18) and the type is list

Comment: then try  `torch.optim.Adam(*parameters_1)`

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c2dd3be47059> in <module>
      1 # set up optimizer
      2 import torch.optim as optim
----> 3 optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(*parameters_1)

TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 7 positional arguments but 63 were given

Comment: I looked at the example that you referred to and I was able to reproduce it OK. Apparently `torch.optim.Adam(parameters) ` is correct. 
try removing typing info from the optimizer parameter in the train_step definition. or just write optimizer:tp.Any.  See if it works